# meteor-up deploy on Amazon EC not working, wait-for-mongo: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27017]

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-up

I have the following in my `mup.json`

```
  // Install MongoDB in the server, does not destroy local MongoDB on future setup
  "setupMongo": true,

  // WARNING: Node.js is required! Only skip if you already have Node.js installed on server.
  "setupNode": true,

  // WARNING: If nodeVersion omitted will setup 0.10.36 by default. Do not use v, only version number.
  "nodeVersion": "0.10.43",

  // Install PhantomJS in the server
  "setupPhantom": false,

  // Show a progress bar during the upload of the bundle to the server.
  // Might cause an error in some rare cases if set to true, for instance in Shippable CI
  "enableUploadProgressBar": true,

  // Application name (No spaces)
  "appName": "myapp",

  // Location of app (local directory)
  "app": "/path/to/myapp",

  // Configure environment
  "env": {
    "PORT": 5555,
    "ROOT_URL": "http://myserver.com"
  },
```

I got this in the `deploy` log

```
Started TaskList: Deploy app 'myapp' (linux)
[myserver.com] - Uploading bundle
[myserver.com] - Uploading bundle: SUCCESS
[myserver.com] - Setting up Environment Variables
[myserver.com] - Setting up Environment Variables: SUCCESS
[myserver.com] - Invoking deployment process
[myserver.com] x Invoking deployment process: FAILED

    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    eding commands with `sudo`, or if
    npm WARN deprecated on Windows, run them from an Administrator prompt.)
    npm WARN deprecated 
    npm WARN deprecated If you're running the version of npm bundled with
    npm WARN deprecated Node.js 0.10 LTS, be aware that the next version of 0.10 LTS
    npm WARN deprecated will be bundled with a version of npm@2, which has some small
    npm WARN deprecated backwards-incompatible changes made to `npm run-script` and
    npm WARN deprecated semver behavior.
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
    js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version

    /usr/lib/node_modules/wait-for-mongo/bin/wait-for-mongo:14
        throw err;
              ^
    Error: TIMEOUTED_WAIT_FOR_MONGO
        at null._onTimeout (/usr/lib/node_modules/wait-for-mongo/lib/waitForMongo.js:20:14)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:121:15)
    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
    .1:27017]
    wait-for-mongo: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27017]
    wait-for-mongo: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27017]
    wait-for-mongo: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27017]
    wait-for-mongo: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27017]
```

when I ssh to the ec2 server and it looks like `mongod` is not started?

```
/opt/myapp$ ps -aux | grep mongod
ubuntu    9566  0.7  2.1 661524 22144 ?        Sl   22:32   0:00 node /usr/bin/wait-for-mongo mongodb://127.0.0.1/myapp 300000
ubuntu    9569  0.0  0.0  10464   916 pts/0    S+   22:33   0:00 grep --color=auto mongod

/opt/myapp$ mongo myapp
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.12
connecting to: myapp
2016-04-05T22:44:07.802+0000 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2016-04-05T22:44:07.803+0000 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

I'm not sure how to gain access to `mongo` on the server, given that I "handed over" responsibility to `meteor-up` with `"setup-mongo":true`.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

**update**
switched to `mupx`, and set `"deployCheckWaitTime": 300` mongo is now loading correctly. But now I am getting this error:

```
/bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:278
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
MongoError: driver is incompatible with this server version
    at Object.Future.wait (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
    at [object Object].MongoConnection._ensureIndex (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:790:1)
    at [object Object].Mongo.Collection._ensureIndex (packages/mongo/collection.js:635:1)
```

It seems to be related to these issues:
https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/issues/841
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5809

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I must had incompatible versions on my system from using `mup` and also `meteor create; meteor mongo` earlier on the ec2 server. I linked `/opt` to an empty folder in a different partition (had space problems) and ran `mupx setup/deploy` again from scratch. This time it worked fine (with Meteor 1.3).

Strangely, I noticed there was no `/opt/nodejs` folder, which was probably a leftover from my first attempt with `mup`.

also, the docker daemon doesn't seem to be running, but I can connect to my mongoDB from an `ssh` session the `mup` way

```
$ mongo myapp // works fine

$ docker exec -it mongodb mongo myapp 
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```